# I need any equation to solve the required operation

Tags: probability-distributions

**I am trying to create a calculator.**
A=low       B=low             C=low
A=low       B=high           C=high
A=high      B=low             C=low
A=high      B=high            C=very-high

**Update**

I am trying to create a calculator.
where **A** is the no.of attempts **B** is the score.I need a grading based on these factors ie **C**. when no.of attempts and score is high, it should be the only case where Grade must be high, remaining all cases grade should be low.

**Example**

Attempts = 5

Score = 4

Grade should be low as attempts and score is low

Attempts = 20

Score = 16

Grade should be VERY-HIGH as both score and attempts is high.

In the above examples both the ratios are equal but i need a higher **weight-age for second case**

Attempts = 5

Score = 50

Grade should be HIGH as attempts is less

Attempts = 50

Score = 15

Grade should be less as score is less

**How can i solve this.I need to confine the grade in between 1 and 10**

Comment: As it stands, this is a meaningless question. Are you trying to find $C$ as a function of $A,B$? If so, try $C = A \land B$.

Comment: **I can give you the exact description** A=guess B=score and C=grade, When guess is small and score is small the grade should also be small...likewise the only condition in which grade should be high is when both guess and score is high...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding I have generated this sample:
[image]

I am assuming a max. value of 100 for A and S.

If this is what you want, the formulas are as follows:

$$R=(A*S)/(100*100)$$

This resulting values have min. value of $0$ and max. of $1$. You could scale this between $1$ and $10$ to get $S$ as follows:

$$S= ((10-1)*(R-Min)/(Max-Min))+Min$$

$$S= ((10-1)*(R-0)/(1-0))+1$$

Note: the division by 100*100 is not really required. You could omit it and change $S$ to be:

$$S= ((10-1)*(R-0)/(100*100-0))+1$$

**Edit**

[image]

As per the new requirement expressed in the note, here is a sample of the modefied formulas:

$$ R=(A*S) * (S/(A+10))$$

Here the value $A*S$ is multiplied by a factor that decreases the total value as A increases to cover the case for the new requirements.

The value of $10$ in the above expression is any value greater than zero so that when $A=0$ you don't get an error.

The max. value of R is when $A=100$ and $S=100$, at these points R=9090.91

$$ S==10*R/9090.91$$

Note that while the above formulas may produce correct numerical values, the may not be suitable to score exams and such because they may not represent fair marking (that requires statistics I don't know).

Comment: I have made a slight updation in my question.As when the attempts is low and score is high(it can be probably a guess)we can call the grade as high and when attempts and score is high the grade should be very-high.The answer you provided is acceptable if you can make these changes.  Thank you

Comment: Now, this is tricky because (R) can't be calculated by multiplication...

Comment: The solution you  made is Fantabulous!! Its the exact measures i can use.Once again THANK YOU @emmad-kareem

Comment: Thank You for spending your time. I have implemented the thing and works like a BOSS!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Then the answer is $C = A \land B$, or whatever symbol you use for conjunction (the 'and' operator, maybe $C=A B$).

Comment: I have edited  the question with atnost details @copper.hat
 Any suggestions ???